# jquery selector syntax including eq

Tags: jquery

I have a number of html structures like this:

```
<div class="item"><p>...</p></div>
```

I want to cycles through them selecting the p elements. I  tried various combinations of the below but I can't seem to get the syntax right - can anyone please help

Thanks

```
for ( var i = 0; i < (jQuery('.item').length); i++ ){
    jQuery (' .item'.eq(i)+ 'p');
```

}

Comment: Use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var paragraphs = $(".item p");
        for (i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
            alert($(paragraphs[i]).html());
        }


    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks - I wanted to use this method - partly to get to grips with how to put variables into a selector, which is hard to find info on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate. You can use find() function to get all the `p` elements in the descendants of current `div` object.

```
jQuery('.item').each(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
    p$ = $(this).find("p");  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
jQuery('.item:eq('+i+') p');
```

or

```
jQuery('.item').eq(i).find('p');
```

Comment: Thanks -does what I wanted it to. I found it hard to find documentation on who to put a variable into a selector.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use `.each()` as others have suggested. But if you wanted to use your way you could do:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < (jQuery('.item').length); i++ ){
    jQuery ('.item:eq(' + i + ') p');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If u want to get all p elements do it with a each instead a for loop:

```
$(".item p").each(function(index,value){
    console.log(index);// will print the position of p element
    console.log($(this).html());// will show you the content of p element
});
```

With this you will pass for all p elements inside your div with class "item" and u can get the index and value of the element, your index will  be .eq(index). But you don't need use .eq cause each will pass for all elements and you will check that console.log will print 0,1,... n p elements.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$(".item p").each(function(){
console.log($(this).html()); //html of p tag
})
```